# jQuery Data Attribute value

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have an array of values taken from inputs (prices[]), I want to add value to an input value based on selected option that have data attribute.

[price input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbSnS.png)
I want to take value from data-price and put the value of data attribute in price[], but when I select, it doesnt work properly just for the first item.

[Newly added product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMe27.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6s1a.png)

```js
$('.products').change(function() {
  let price = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
  $('.prices').val(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <label for="product">Product</label>
  <select class="form-control kt-select2 products" id="kt_select2_2" name="products[]" required>
    <option selected disabled>Select a product</option>
    <option value="1" data-price="1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="3">Product 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">Product Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control prices" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter product price" value="0" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code here so that we can reproduce your problem. Don't put it in an image

Comment: I've converted your code to a runable snippet.  As you can see, it works fine.

Comment: "*it doesnt work properly just for the first item*" - do you mean the "select a product" option, which is the "first item".   What are you *expecting* to happen if the user attempts to select this?  It can't be selected as it's disabled.  Remove the `disabled` attribute and give it `data-price=""` if you want it to be selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the prices element that belongs to that particular product, i created a div with the class of product-wrap that has both the select and the price input, you should select a element that has both inputs

```js
$('.products').change(function() {
  let price = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
  $(this).closest('.product-wrap').find('.prices').val(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-wrap">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <label for="product">Product</label>
    <select class="form-control kt-select2 products" id="kt_select2_2" name="products[]" required>
      <option selected disabled>Select a product</option>
      <option value="1" data-price="1">Product 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-price="2">Product 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-price="3">Product 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="price">Product Price</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control prices" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter product price" value="0" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-wrap">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <label for="product">Product</label>
    <select class="form-control kt-select2 products" id="kt_select2_2" name="products[]" required>
      <option selected disabled>Select a product</option>
      <option value="1" data-price="1">Product 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-price="2">Product 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-price="3">Product 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="price">Product Price</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control prices" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter product price" value="0" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```